# Mapbox Studio - layer ordering / z-index

Tags: mapbox

I am following the [source quickstart](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/source-quickstart/) tutorial.  I have followed the tutorial all the way through, and am having trouble displaying the earthquake data (red circles) above the land vectors.

According to the [symbol drawing order documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/symbol-drawing-order/):

> “Higher” layers obscure “lower” ones.

However I'm not finding this to be the case.  Please see attached screenshot:

[image]

The 'earthquakes' layer is the 'higher' layer, I think.  I am using the 'Comic!' base map styles.  Since the road lines also appear to 'mask off' the land vectors and show the earthquake data below, I'm wondering if this is causing the issue, but looking through the styles there's nothing obvious I can see.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is correct, however the `comp-op` family of CartoCSS properties affect how the colors of different layers interact with each other. In this case, the `marker-comp-op: screen` from the quickstart example was designed to work well over a darker satellite background, but becomes nearly invisible over solid white.

If you remove the `marker-comp-op` property or change it to a different compositing operation such as `multiply` the earthquake markers should show up fine.